# Moving fixed nodes in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using D3's forced layout to display a graph. Now, I require that the nodes change their positions when any node is clicked.

I looked up other related StackOverflow questions but that didn't help me.

The code for render is as follows :

```
var render = function(graph){

       /* var loading = svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", width / 2)
            .attr("y", height / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Simulating. One moment please…");*/


        force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links);

        //Enter phase for links.
        link.enter().append("line");

        //Update phase for links
            link
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes,function(d){return d.name;});

        //Enter phase for nodes
        var node_g = node.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class","node")
            .on("dblclick",nodeClick)
            .call(force.drag);

        //Update phase for nodes

        node_g.append("text")
            .attr("class","NodeLabel")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.name;
            });

         var nodeCirlce = node_g.append("circle");

        nodeCirlce
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })

        node_g.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

            force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node_g.attr("transform",function(d){
                    return "translate("+ d.x+","+ d.y+")";
                });

            //TODO : Add attr change for node text as well.
        });
```

And the code for the node click handler looks like this :

```
var nodeClick = function(d,i){
        //Translate the graph to center around the selected node.
        var x_trans = x_cent - d.x;
        var y_trans = y_cent - d.y;
        var nodes = oldGraph.nodes;

        for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
            var node = nodes[i];
            node.x = node.x + 1000;
            node.y = node.y + 1000;
            node.fixed = true;
        }
        //oldGraph.nodes = updateNodes(nodes,oldGraph.links);
        render(oldGraph);
        //setTimeout(function(){layout("json/HUMAN-1g.json");},000);

    };
```

However, the node positions don't get updated.

Comment: You need to call the `tick` handler function after updating the data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : Tried that, didn't work. Modified the render function as follows :
force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links);
 force.start();
            for (var i = n * n; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
            force.stop();

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links);
......
});

I removed the force.on handler as well. (Replaced that code without the handler after update phase for nodes and links)

Comment: can you put this up on a fiddle..

Comment: Run the code inside the `tick` handler function in `nodeClick`.

Comment: @Cyril   
http://jsfiddle.net/Sheno/nn5nw5fz/21/#&togetherjs=Lp2UQcnjHz

Comment: @LarsKotthoff : Thanks. That helped a lot. 
So, if I just want to translate the nodes, I dont even need the render function it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the data, you need to run the code that updates the positions in the DOM. This is exactly what you have in the `tick` event handler function:

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node_g.attr("transform",function(d){
                return "translate("+ d.x+","+ d.y+")";
```

I recommend pulling this out into a separate function and then setting it as the `tick` handler function and calling it from your `nodeClick()` function. To be clear, you *don't* need to call `render()` from the `nodeClick()` function.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.
I moved from a radial-tree layout to force layout, and tried to just copy code analogously.

Comment: Is there a way to animate the movement? I tried `.transition()` but no fun =(